# Spark - How to run a standalone cluster locally

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

Is there the possibility to run the *Spark standalone cluster* locally on just one machine (which is basically different from just developing jobs locally (i.e., `local[*]`))?.

So far I am running 2 different VMs to build a cluster, what if I could run a standalone cluster on the very same machine, having *for instance* three different JVMs running?

Could something like having multiple loopback addresses do the trick?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

yes you can do it, launch one master and one worker node and you are good to go

launch master

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
```

launch worker

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker  spark://localhost:7077 -c 1 -m 512M
```

run SparkPi example

```
./bin/spark-submit  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi   --master spark://localhost:7077  lib/spark-examples-1.2.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

[Apache Spark Standalone Mode Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

Comment: Thanks, but what if I need 2 or more workers working in parallel?
Could that be possible?

Comment: @luke you can run multiple worker using launch worker command in different shell tabs

Answer (score 10):

A small update as for the **latest version (the 2.1.0)**, the default is to bind the master to the hostname, so when starting a worker locally use the output of `hostname`:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker  spark://`hostname`:7077 -c 1 -m 512M
```

And to run an example, simply run the following command:

```
bin/run-example SparkPi
```

Comment: Thanks, no longer getting : worker cannot connect to master

Answer (score 8):

If you can't find the `./sbin/start-master.sh` file on your machine, you can start the master also with

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

Answer (score 2):

More simply,

```
./sbin/start-all.sh
```

On your local machine there will be master and one worker launched.

```
./bin/spark-submit  \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi   \
--master spark://localhost:7077  \
examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.1.jar 10000
```

A sample application is submitted. For monitoring via Web UI:

```
Master UI:      http://localhost:8080
Worker UI:      http://localhost:8081
Application UI: http://localhost:4040
```