# How to Upload JAR file to Serverr

Tags: scala, apache-spark, server, jar, cluster-computing

I have created JAR file of my Scala Spark Code and run that JAR file on my local system successfully. I want to execute that JAR file on a Cluster and for that I have to Push JAR file to Server. How can I upload my JAR file to server?

I used Maven to create JAR file

Comment: `scp`, `ftp`, upload to Google drive and downdload on the other side using `curl`, and many other ways. Just Google how to upload a file to a remote server and / or ask to the administrator of that server for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setJars to tell Spark where to find jar files you want to deploy to the cluster before you build SparkSession.

```
sparkConf.setJars(List(conf.getString("spark.oneJar")))
val sparkSession:SparkSession=SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

In my case I was using maven-shade-plugin to build oneJar in compile time, and then it  was deployed to Spark Cluster from target directory.

Comment: How can I deploy Spark Cluster?

Comment: That's completely different topic. You should create another question or start by looking at the documentation http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually or existing questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074272/spark-how-to-run-a-standalone-cluster-locally

Answer (score 0):

Simply login to your node in local spark cluster and execute the below command in terminal

```
$ spark-submit --class your.package.name.ClassName /home/username/your-created-jar-using-maven.jar
```

Where `/home/username/your-created-jar-using-maven.jar` is the location where your JAR file is kept & `your.package.name.ClassName` is fully qualified class location.

Refer for available option for spark-submit : https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-submit.html

Comment: This will not work. We have to push first JAR file to server than from server we have to execute spark-submit command

Comment: It is expected that you would push the JAR into any node of the spark cluster either using scp command or SFTP protocol. I have already told to login into a spark node, which means the files needs to be present in the node machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at using [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/). Connect to your cluster using SSH then you'll be able to just drag and drop the files.

[image]